# How to create a object that uses prototype's property

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to create something similar to static languages "static field". Basically: counter property should be incremented every time the init function is called, but no matter on which instance. This is a sample code I'm using to test  ( http://jsfiddle.net/HK8BY/2/ ) :

```
var Widget = {
    counter: 0,
    init: function () {
        this.counter++;
        console.log("init called: " + this.counter);
    }
};

var t1 = Object.create(Widget);
var t2 = Object.create(Widget);
t1.init(); // should print: init called 1
t2.init(); // should print: init called 2
console.log(t1);
console.log(t2);
```

Currently when I console.log instanes, I see that both **proto** and instance contain counter property. I thought that with this approach, only **proto** will have it.

So how can I change it to have only counter in prototype?

Comment: the problem is your *access* via `this` within `init()`. Simply spoken, you may just replace `this` with `Widget` and it will work as expected.

Comment: Ok, it works :) Thanks. But could you also elaborate why this.counter doesn't use prototype's counter ? I though that JavaScript engine accesses prototype's fields if no field is set on "this".

Comment: You should write an answer - this is one of possible solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var twitter = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    return {
        init : function() { counter++; console.log("init called: " + counter); }
    };
}()); 

var t1 = Object.create(twitter);
var t2 = Object.create(twitter);

t1.init();
t2.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HK8BY/1/

So you just create IEFE (Immediately executed function expression) that returns the desired object. The `counter` variable is available to the closure of that object's `init` function.

Comment: I've updated jsfiddle to be the same code as in the question. sorry

Comment: Splendid! But is it possible to achieve the same result with prototype?

Comment: @dragonfly: this solution is a bit better, because you don't have a direct access to the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
var Widget = {
    init: function () {
        this.prototype.counter++;
        console.log("init called: " + this.counter);
    }
};
Widget.prototype.counter = 0;

var t1 = Object.create(Widget);
var t2 = Object.create(Widget);
t1.init();
t2.init();
console.log(t1);
console.log(t2);
```

Comment: It does not work: Widget.prototype.counter = 0; throws error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'counter' of undefined ".

Comment: strange... uninitialized prototype, you can initialize it with `Widget.prototype = {};` before use.

Comment: But it won't be the "real" prototype. As far as I remember, only function have real prototype property, which is then used when "new" operator is used with a function... But I would rather have an expert confirm that

Comment: Any object (not a scalar) have a prototype, in JS function is an object. zerkms's solution is better, I just tried minimal modifications with existing code.

Comment: But the prototype that you are mentioning (that any object has) is the __proto__ - do this: console.log(Widget.__proto__);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Widget)); . Also yes: function is an object, but object is not a function. And Widget is an object: console.log(typeof Widget); . Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate static fields by defining properties on a constructor function, but if you prefer to use `Object.create` in place of `new` then this might not be a solution you want to consider.

```
function Widget() {
    this.init()
};

Widget.counter = 0;

Widget.prototype.init = function() {
    this.constructor.counter++;
    console.log("init called: " + this.constructor.counter);
};
```